# how can i get different data from three tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

Query:

```
select te.empno, te.ename, te.mgr
from test te
where te.deptno=10 and
      not exists (select 1 from t1 te1 where te1.deptno=te.deptno and te1.empno=te.empno) and
      not exists (select 1 from t te2 where te2.mgr=te.mgr);
```

table_name:te

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB      MGR    HIREDATE    SAL COMM    DEPTNO
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   -   17-Nov-81   5000    -   10
7782    CLARK   MANAGER  7839   9-Jun-81    2450    -   10
7934    MILLER  CLERK    7782   23-Jan-82   1300    -   10
123    Ranga    -        7566   -              -    -   10
124    srinu    -         123   -             - -       10
```

table_name:t1

```
EMPNO   DEPTNO
7782    10
7934    10
7839    10
```

table_name:t

```
MGR     NAME
7566    aaa
```

Here I have three different tables.  I want to required three tables different data.  Is it possible to get the different please help on this?

Required output:

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB      MGR    HIREDATE    SAL COMM    DEPTNO
123     Ranga    -        7566   -              -    -   10
124     srinu    -         123   -             - -       10
```

Comment: `I want to required three tables different data` what do u mean by that?

Comment: The query - especially the not-exists for mgr and the required output seem to contradict each other.

Comment: @minigeek sorry by mistake printing .i want require data from the te table different columns based on the three tables but i will try above query it will be generate like this                                                          EMPNO ENAME MGR
124          srinu 123 but i want require above mention output.thanks

Comment: @minigeek if data is there then it will be given 1 value

Comment: Please show us `your output` and output you want ..so one can understand easily where you are going wrong

Comment: @RavindraHV is it possible or not give any solution please?

Comment: @minigeek i already mention required output in my question .could you please see above?

Comment: Why do you want the row with `empno=123`? It has `mgr=7566` which is present in `t`.

Comment: @mik actually my requirement is  we have three different table .here i need  to match the three tables based on the above query.if suppose empno not matched based on the te and t1 tables it will shows  non matched rows and i need to match the same scenario t table mgr is present but emono is different so i need required mis matched data all the tables

Comment: @swamy if I understand correctly, you should probably remove `not` before second `exists`, but in this case you would not get the row with `empno=124`; on the other hand removing the second `exists` totally would give you what is "required"

Comment: Please get someone with a better knowledge of English to help you formulate your question. After so many exchanges, it is still not clear what the requirement is, and in this case it seems almost sure it's the language barrier. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select te.empno, te.ename, te.mgr from test te
WHERE te.deptno=10
AND not exists(select 1 from t1 te1 where te1.deptno=te.deptno and te1.empno=te.empno)
AND  exists(select 1 from t te2 where te2.mgr=te.mgr)
union
select te.empno, te.ename, te.mgr from test te
WHERE te.deptno=10
AND  not exists(select 1 from t1 te1 where te1.deptno=te.deptno and te1.empno=te.empno)
AND not  exists(select 1 from t te2 where te2.mgr=te.mgr)
```

this is for the solution above the question

Comment: If this solves, you can remove the second `select`, remove the `AND exists ...` condition, add a `distinct` and get the same result with much less code

Answer (score -1):

I think that you only need two tables. 
if i understood correctly you only need two tables.

```
select te.EMPNO, te.ENAME, te.JOB, t.MGR,t.NAME as "MGRNAME",te.HIREDATE, te.SAL, te.COMM, te.DEPNO
from te
join t on t.MGR=te.MGR
```

OR if you need to use the 3 tables:

```
select te.EMPNO, te.ENAME, te.JOB, t.MGR,t.NAME as "MGRNAME",te.HIREDATE, te.SAL, te.COMM, te.DEPNO
from te
join t1 on t1.EMPNO=te.EMPNO and t1.DEPNO=te.DEPTNO
join t on t.MGR=te.MGR
```

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience i need to required non matched rows.please help on this?thanks

Comment: @swamy you need to include the data that are in te table but not in others? That's it?

Comment: SELECT pa_num,
partner_id,
product_line
FROM IF_LSP_PANUM_MAP ilp
WHERE icp.country_code=i_workflow_keys
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
 FROM sq_partner partner, sq_lsp lsp
 WHERE partner.partner_id = lsp.company_id
 AND partner.country_code =ilp.country_code
 AND partner.partner_id=ilp.partner_id
 AND partner.active = 'Y')
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
FROM sq_product_line pl
WHERE pl.PRODUCT_LINE_ID=ilp.product_line
); this is my requirement

Comment: @swamy This query does not have tha above tables. What is that? You need to provide a clear "goal". The query that i post works for the examples in your question. 
I suggest the following. Run the query I posted and see the results.
Or try that query:
select te.EMPNO, te.ENAME, te.JOB, t.MGR,t.NAME as "MGRNAME",te.HIREDATE, te.SAL, te.COMM, te.DEPNO
from teste te
left join t on t.MGR=te.MGR
where t.MGR is null

Comment: i got solution could you please check and is it right or not let me know please?